# CoreData+RestKit: saving nested objects maintaining parent relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

Given two Core Data entities A and B, where A has a relation 1-N with B, I'm loading them with RestKit through a web service returning an array of A objects, each one containing an array of B object, such as:

```
{
  "A": [
  {
    "idA": 1,
    "B": [
      {
        "idB": 1, 
        "idA": 1,
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
      },
      {
        "idB": 2,
        "idA": 1,
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "idA": 2,
    "B": [
      {
        "idB": 3,
        "idA": 2,
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
      },
      {
        "idB": 4,
        "idA": 2,
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As the whole process takes up quite a lot of time, I'm executing it only at app startup.
Later on there are situations where I need just to update B objects through the same ws (maintaining the relation from A->B and avoiding duplicates): is this feasible with RestKit?

If it may be of any help take into account that the B object contains a reference to its parent ("idA" key).

Many thanks,
DAN

Comment: How would you do it? As there is a mapping already associated to the route path of the existing service, the only solution I've thought about is creating a new web service returning only B objects.

Comment: presumably the data has a different key path if it's just B objects in the response ?

Comment: with a new ws yes, I was wondering if I could achieve the same result with just one service (the one which response is in the question)

Comment: You son is a dictionary with A as the key, presumably if you get B instances back the key is different...

Comment: I don't get what you're saying, the keys of B will be different for new objects

Comment: Show an example of the JSON for the second request response

Comment: There is no second response :) As stated I would like to get B objects with the same web service/same response.
If this is not feasible with RestKit I'll think about creating a second web service which will return only B objects.

Comment: So if the response will be exactly the same format it will just work without any new mappings

Comment: That's correct but I need I way to get/update ONLY B objects thought the same service (with a second mapping). The whole process (getting both A and B) takes a lot of time (A has many other attributes) and I do it only at app startup, but when the app comes back from background I need to update only B objects. As said, if this is not feasible, I'll create a separate web service returning only B objects.

Comment: most likely the time consuming bit is the networking not the mapping...

Comment: unfortunately it is the mapping, the response arrives in about 150ms (80KB gzipped) but looking at the console log the mapping takes about 20 seconds

Comment: Wow - what is the mapping like? Are you using unique ids? Are you using an in-memory cache!?!

Comment: Yes I'm using unique ids. There are about 200 A objects, each one containing about ten attributes and five 1-N relationships with objects like B, where N can range from 0 to about 20. I've tried with RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache instead of RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache and it takes about 15 instead of 20 seconds. This is why I'm looking for a way to update only B objects.